# Initial scene at the World Health Organization

Tags: plot-explanation, world-war-z

When Gerry wakes up in the WHO the two guys grill him about who he is and what he is doing there as he's tied down. They make the comment "you know what we are don't you" or something to that affect. I didn't understand how to take what they were trying to imply to Gerry.

I took that to mean they would kill him if his identity was proven; e.g. as if the WHO is a cover for a secret government hit-man crew. As the movie progressed the guys in the WHO turned out to simply be lab nerds so I don't understand why they were attempting masquerade as assassins of some sort.

Is there some well-known conspiracy theory about the WHO that this scene is trying to play on?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're misinterpreting their intentions. They're a lab containing extremely contagious diseases. That's a highly classified facility, probably with extremely high security in normal times. To anyone who isn't a high-ranking UN or WHO operative, this facility is *strictly* off limits.

There wasn't anything said to imply they're assassins. Just that if he wasn't who he was supposed to be, they'd toss him out. Of course, with Zeke wondering around, that's equivalent to a death sentence.